# How can one deploy common JavaScript and images to two different EARs while not having to maintain two versions of each file

Tags: java, javascript, deployment, ear

I have a Struts web app deployed to an EAR that has some pretty extensive JavaScript. I now need to create a new web app that will be deployed to a new EAR but will probably need to share most if not all of the JavaScript and some images from the first application. What's the best way to avoid code duplication so I don't have to put a copy of each JavaScript file in each EAR in my development environment?

Comment: You could maintain the Javascript in a separate `.jar` library and serve it as a resource, not as a static file. That way the JS content would be a regular dependency in your project setup. Unfortunately there isn't a straightforward universal way to do this because you need at the very least a servlet that will send the file from the .jar. (Depending on your web framework you might already have this available.)

Comment: @millimoose, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Done, along with a bunch of other considerations that came to mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could maintain the Javascript in a separate .jar library and serve it as a resource, not as a static file. That way the JS content would be a regular dependency in your project setup. Unfortunately there isn't a straightforward universal way to do this because you need at the very least a servlet that will send the file from the .jar. (Depending on your web framework you might already have this available.)

This also has some performance implications, but for a line of business application you probably don't need to optimize the load time of your internal Javascripts all that heavily.

Another alternative would be doing this at the source control level, using something like [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I'll probably accept your answer if there's nothing easier that comes up in the next few days but if this is the least complicated solution, I think we'll probably go with duplicating the code which will create a maintenance headache but will probably be better for us than using a custom servlet.

Comment: @Chris Of these options, I'd only use serving as a resource if the web framework that's used already supports this out of the box. (E.g. Wicket with its [`ResourceReference`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ResourceReference.html) ). The source control solution is probably simpler but the specifics depend on what system you're using; and Git at least doesn't automatically update submodules, so you'd want to add that as a build step. (There's also some gotchas about making changes while in the submodule.)